# url keeps redirecting to a page

Tags: redirect, rewrite-rules

I have theme options pages `www.website.com/wp-admin/themes.php?page=avada_options`
but problem is when ever i go that page it redirect to `www.website.com/store-manager/`
I checked the rewrite, even deleted it. No errors on the page. I have no idea how to even debug this out
Please help

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by just clearing the cache. If anyone facing similar issue you may try

1. Deleting the browser cache, or trying in incognito mode
2. Contact hosting as ask them to clear any server cache or disable any caching features they have
3. Save the permalink again or delete the rewrite table content in the database - wp-option> rewrite_rules
4. If still does not work -> try deactivating all the plugins/themes and find the plugin/theme causing the issue.
5. Otherwise, it will be caching issue again